# Radio Group Android stays on default

Tags: android, radio-button

I was searching on Google and StackOverflow for any solution, and i found hundereds of them but none of them worked in my case.

I have 3 RadioButtons and as it should be only one is selectable.

Now i want know which Radio Button is selected when I push the "Visit" Button.
My Function for the VisitButton is called but when i try to read the RadioButton the result is always the same.

It does not matter which one I select, it always chooses the default button.

I tried a variety of different approaches, onChangeCheckListener, onClickListener but none of them seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code-snippet:

```
MicrolabB  = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Microlab);
        MoodleB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Moodle);
        ISAB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ISA);
        PortalSelect = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.PortalSelect);
        VISIT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Visit);
        MicrolabB.setOnClickListener(this);
        ISAB.setOnClickListener(this);
        MoodleB.setOnClickListener(this);

    public void VisitWebPage(View v){
        if(v.getId()==R.id.Visit){

            if(MicrolabB.isChecked())
                ApduNFC.Portal =1;
            if(ISAB.isChecked())
                ApduNFC.Portal=2;
            if(MoodleB.isChecked())
                ApduNFC.Portal=3;

            Intent intent = new Intent(Start.this,ApduNFC.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

And my XML:

```
 <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/PortalSelect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/Microlab"
                android:layout_width="133dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Microlab"
                android:clickable="true"
                 />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/ISA"
                android:layout_width="126dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="IS-A"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:checked="true" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/Moodle"
                android:layout_width="116dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Moodle"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Visit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:onClick="VisitWebPage"
            android:text="Visit" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the Problem.

```
public void VisitWebPage(View v){
        final RadioGroup PortalSelect = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.PortalSelect);
        int ID = PortalSelect.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(v.getId()==R.id.Visit){
        int rb1Id = MicrolabB.getId();
            if(ID == MicrolabB.getId())
                Log.d("RB Selected","1");
            if(ID == ISAB.getId())
                Log.d("RB Selected","2");
            if(ID == MoodleB.getId())
                Log.d("RB Selected","3");   

            Intent intent = new Intent(Start.this,ApduNFC.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

After I put in the Line

```
final RadioGroup PortalSelect = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.PortalSelect);
```

in the VisitWebPage Function everything seems to work. I have no Idea why, because I defined the Radio Group before in this class. But I'm happy that it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

At first, in this example you're surely do not need listeners on RadioButtons.

The best option to get selected button is from `PortalSelect.getCheckedRadioButtonId().` 
You will get id of the RadioButton checked.

Don't forget to check if id exists; By default, RadioGroup initialized with none of the RadioButtons checked;

Refer to Google RadioGroup site: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html

Comment: What do you mean by checking if ID exists? The second button is the default one.

Answer (score 0):

In your `VisitWebPage` add first `PortalSelect.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` like

```
public void VisitWebPage(View v){
    if(v.getId()==R.id.Visit){

        int selectedId = PortalSelect.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        if(selectedId == MicrolabB.getId())
            Log.d("RB Selected","1");
        if(selectedId ==ISAB.getId())
            Log.d("RB Selected","2");
        if(selectedId ==MoodleB.getId())
            Log.d("RB Selected","3");

        //Intent intent = new Intent(Start.this,ApduNFC.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried this, but it still jumps into the default button. In this Case the "ISAB" Button even if I chose an other one.

Comment: try to delete this line in your xml `android:checked="true"` from the ISAB radiobutton

Comment: Now it enters in none of them. It jumps over all of them step by step. My ID seems to be -1 all the time.

Comment: I checked your code in my phone it works well with my modifications please check your `Portal` variable initialisation in your `ApduNFC` class

Comment: Thanks for testing it. But it doesn't seem to work on my Samsung S3. I made all your changes as you said. `Portal` is defined as static and public. But my Function does not enter in one of the "if" questions. Did you get a "normal" ID out of `getCheckedRadioButtonId` ?

Comment: i edited my answer for checking if it works or not, please check what is printed in the logcat

Comment: Nothing is printed in the logcat because my programm never gets to the print-command due to the fact that ID is always -1 :(